# How is a GAN trained at the beginning?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I understand the general overview but I want to know more in-depth about the training. What exactly happens in the first two iterations of training? Is it the generator or the discriminator that gets trained first? Is a validation set ever used for training a GAN? If so, would it be for the generator or the discriminator?

Answer (score 0):

Every iteration is the same.

We use a batch of real and a batch of generated (fake) examples in each iteration. Those two batches are of the same size, that we get to choose.

Both Generator and Discriminator are trained at the same time, iteration-wise. G gets a random vector as input, while D gets real examples.

But, inside of an iteration, you first have to generate a batch of fake examples. Then, you feed real examples into D, and finally you feed generated examples into D, in each iteration. D first learns parameters (weights) on real examples, and then uses those weights on fake examples. Then, yoy calculate D loss, and then G loss, and pass them to an optimizer, which tries to minimize them.

There are no validation and test sets. You just want to minimize the losses in D and G.

Theoretically, you want your D to tell with 50% probability that an example is real, because in that case it's unable to distinguish between real and fake examples, which is what you wanted. It can only guess. It's like flipping a coin. In that case, G does a good job of generating examples that are similar to real ones.